# Java - Spring: use @Value convert a int[] to Integer[]

Tags: java, arrays, spring, generics, casting

Is there a way to have spring framework 4 annotation @Value convert or cast a int[] array to Integer[] array?
I know that it is possible to convert an int to Integer. But I am not sure about the array

I am getting the int[] from a configuration file

```
tcp.port=20001,20002,20003
```

and using spring's @Value to read those values as a Integer[]

```
@Value("${tcp.port}")
private Integer[] tcpPorts;
```

I cannot use int[] because of a generic method in the code. Is there a way to convert/cast int[] to Integer[] with spring?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused by your snippet. Are you just demonstrating the `int` to `Integer` conversion? Where are you getting the `int[]` from?

Comment: Sorry about that.. this is just to show that there is a way to convert int to Integer. I am trying to find out if there is a way to convert int[] to Integer[] using spring's @Value

Comment: Show us your `int[]`. Where does it come from?

Comment: it is not duplicate because I am trying to convert the integer array @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Yeah, the accepted answer in the duplicate works for `Integer[]` the same as it does for `List<Integer>`.

Comment: And you could always use `toArray` from the `List` to get an `Integer[]`.